# Is it possible to remove Appium session (and all Appium resources on device), but leave app opened on iOS (real device)?

Tags: ios, appium, python-appium

Is it possible to remove Appium session and all Appium resources on the device, but leave an app opened on a real iOS device?

The thing is that I need to execute driver.quit to clean all Appium resources, but leave the app itself opened

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to update `deleteSession` method in *node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/build/lib/driver.js* to remove `await this.proxyCommand(`/session/${this.sessionId}`, 'DELETE');`